# Is there any way to make some items of recyclerView unclickable or clickable on specific conditions?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a list of levels of game using recyclerView. If level 1 is not completed, other levels will be locked, if level 1 is completed level 2 will be unlocked and so on.
Need help on this.

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Can you please provide recycler view code snippet? also it would be great if you add any reference image as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `RecyclerViewAdapter` and then override the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter, where you can update the clickability and appearance of each item based on the level's completion status.

Check this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,int)

Answer (score 0):

you can control the clickability of items in a RecyclerView based on specific conditions. You can achieve this by customizing the behavior of your RecyclerView.Adapter

Assuming you have a RecyclerView and an Adapter set up, you can follow these steps:

1.Modify Adapter: Inside your RecyclerView.Adapter class, override the onBindViewHolder method. In this method, you can enable or disable the click action based on your specific conditions.

```
class YourAdapter(private val itemList: List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

// ... other methods and ViewHolder implementation ...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = itemList[position]

    // Set click listener conditionally
    if (yourSpecificCondition) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle click action
        }
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null) // Remove click listener
    }

    // Bind your data to the ViewHolder
}
```

}

In the code above:

Replace **yourSpecificCondition** with your actual condition that determines whether an item should be clickable or not.

If the condition is met, the setOnClickListener is set, enabling the click action. If not, it's set to null, disabling the click action.

**RecyclerView Item Click Handling:**
If you want to handle click events when the items are clickable, implement the item click handling logic inside the **setOnClickListener** block in the onBindViewHolder method.

**Notify Data Changes:**
Whenever your condition changes, make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to update the RecyclerView and reflect the changes in clickability.

and finally call this method

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: ```onBindViewHolder``` is called lots of times and may affect performance, to set listeners better do it in Holder constructor or class